# Zkemkeeper.dll support which biometric devices?

Tags: c#, dll, biometrics

I am working with biometric device (attendance device) to fetch all attendance from it using zkemkeeper.dll

I fetch the attendance from essl biometric device sucessfully, but when i am trying to fetch attendance from realtime biometric device I am not able not fetch.

please suggest me the list of device support zkemkeeper.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Is Here -

```
public zkemkeeper.CZKEM axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();
private void btnconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        bool bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(ip_address_of_your_machine, 4370);   // 4370 is port no of attendance machine
        if (bIsConnected == true)
        {
         MessageBox.Show("Device Connected Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Device Not Connect");
        }
    }

    Catch( (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

[**Connecting and Reading Data From Biometric Attendance Device Using Zkemkeeper.dll in C#.Net**](http://www.jaskumar.com/2016/07/connecting-and-reading-data-from.html)

Comment: It is better to post details in the answer instead of a link. If the link stops working, the answer is lost.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen: I am using this DLL to connect to a finger print device called U160 from the vendor ZktEco, This works for all the devices in my factory across multiple sites (NOTE: we have atlease 100 devices installed across multiple manufacturing plants in China) 
But only for 4 of these devices I get the error code -6 is there documentation that explains the meaning of this error code -6..??

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse I am getting -7. Did you find any solution?

Comment: can anyone convert that code into delphi? or is it possible to do that on delphi?

Answer (score 1):

```
public zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();

/********************************************************************************************************************************************
 * Before you refer to this demo,we strongly suggest you read the development manual deeply first.                                           *
 * This part is for demonstrating the communication with your device.There are 3 communication ways: "TCP/IP","Serial Port" and "USB Client".*
 * The communication way which you can use duing to the model of the device.                                                                 *
 * *******************************************************************************************************************************************/
#region Communication
private bool bIsConnected = false;//the boolean value identifies whether the device is connected
private int iMachineNumber = 1;//the serial number of the device.After connecting the device ,this value will be changed.

//If your device supports the TCP/IP communications, you can refer to this.
//when you are using the tcp/ip communication,you can distinguish different devices by their IP address.
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string ip)
{

    if (ip == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("IP and Port cannot be null", "Error");
        return;
    }
    int idwErrorCode = 0;

    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    if (btnConnect.Text == "DisConnect")
    {
        axCZKEM1.Disconnect();
        bIsConnected = false;
        btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
        lblState.Text = "Current State:DisConnected";
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        return;
    }

    bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(ip, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
    if (bIsConnected == true)
    {
        btnConnect.Text = "DisConnect";
        btnConnect.Refresh();
        lblState.Text = "Current State:Connected";
        iMachineNumber = 1;//In fact,when you are using the tcp/ip communication,this parameter will be ignored,that is any integer will all right.Here we use 1.
        axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535);//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
    }
    else
    {
        axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
    }
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}

//Download the attendance records from the device(For both Black&White and TFT screen devices).
private void btnGetGeneralLogData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bIsConnected == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please connect the device first", "Error");
        return;
    }

    string sdwEnrollNumber = "";
    int idwTMachineNumber=0;
    int idwEMachineNumber=0;
    int idwVerifyMode=0;
    int idwInOutMode=0;
    int idwYear=0;
    int idwMonth=0;
    int idwDay=0;
    int idwHour=0;
    int idwMinute=0;
    int idwSecond = 0;
    int idwWorkcode = 0;

    int idwErrorCode=0;
    int iGLCount = 0;
    int iIndex = 0;

    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    lvLogs.Items.Clear();
    axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, false);//disable the device
    if (axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber))//read all the attendance records to the memory

    {
        while (axCZKEM1.SSR_GetGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber, out sdwEnrollNumber, out idwVerifyMode,
                   out idwInOutMode, out idwYear, out idwMonth, out idwDay, out idwHour, out idwMinute, out idwSecond, ref idwWorkcode))//get records from the memory
        {
            iGLCount++;
            lvLogs.Items.Add(iGLCount.ToString());
            lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(sdwEnrollNumber);//modify by Darcy on Nov.26 2009
            lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwVerifyMode.ToString());
            lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwInOutMode.ToString());
            lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwYear.ToString() + "-" + idwMonth.ToString() + "-" + idwDay.ToString() + " " + idwHour.ToString() + ":" + idwMinute.ToString() + ":" + idwSecond.ToString());
            lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwWorkcode.ToString());
            iIndex++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);

        if (idwErrorCode != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Reading data from terminal failed,ErrorCode: " + idwErrorCode.ToString(),"Error");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No data from terminal returns!","Error");
        }
    }
    axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);//enable the device
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```